# Is there a concise one liner to process and replace values in a dictionary? (using some form of dictionary comprehension)

Tags: python, dictionary

say you have a class like

```
class Foo:
  bar = {"hello": 123, "world": 456}
```

And I want to define `Foo.bar` such that for all the keys and values of `bar`, all even values are replaced with 0.

Is there a clean way to do that in one line? The issue is that the dictionary `{"hello": 123, "world": 456}` is not stored into a variable yet (I want `bar` to be defined with the processing already happened)

So the below is impossible because `d` is not a variable, but it feels (to me) like `d` has to be defined to do the one liner I'm asking for.

```
class Foo:
  bar = {key: (d[key] if not d[key] % 2 else 0) for key in {"hello": 123, "world": 456}}
```

Is what I'm asking for impossible?

Comment: You could iterate `for key, value in {...}.items()`

Comment: that's not a one liner solution, you cant store the output of that into `bar`

Comment: Yes it is. Replace your `for key in {...}` with what I showed

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of where this would be useful? If you've specified the dictionary in code, it's easier to just change the values of the dictionary definition than to go this roundabout way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest, but if it involves a loop outside the context of dictionary comprehension it factually does not work. If you feel differently leave an answer below

Comment: if the dictionary has 1,000,000 key value entries it's not feasible to edit each line.

Comment: So the source dict is actually hardcoded there in the code? And you want to embed a little extra code to modify it?

Comment: yeah basically @nocomment

Comment: If you really have so many entries there that you can't do it manually, then that's most certainly data, not code, and should be in a data file, not in a code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary's `.items()` instead of just iterating over the dictionary (which is equivalent to iterating over its keys)

```
bar = {key: (value if value % 2 else 0) for key, value in {"hello": 123, "world": 456}.items()}
```

This feels icky to me, because it's unnecessary work to first define the dictionary and then iterate over all its contents. Especially for the case of a dictionary containing a million entries you mention in your comments.
I'd suggest you programmatically modify your dictionary and output the modified dictionary, and then use that output instead to define your class variable.

In a separate script, do:

```
import json
bar = {key: (value if value % 2 else 0) for key, value in {"hello": 123, "world": 456}.items()}
with open('bar_dict.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(bar, f)
```

Then, copy the contents of `bar_dict.json` into the definition of `bar` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo:
    bar = {k: 0 if v % 2 == 0 else v for k, v in {"hello": 123, "world": 456}.items()}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand the need for a 1 liner. When you write to a class, you can access the attributes of the class while it is loading into memory.

```
class Foo:
    bar = dict(hello=123,world=456)
    bar = {k:(Foo.bar[k] if Foo.bar[k]%2 else 0) for k in Foo.bar}
```

Comment: would you not agree that defining the same variable twice as a static variable looks ugly (and slightly unreadable)? especially if it can be condensed into one line without too much hassle like shown in the other answers

Comment: clearly, but you can give them different names if you like. the point is there is no need to make the problem more difficult, if you have need to access the variable you simply specify the class name first.

Comment: `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined` - So much for *"simply specify the class name"* ...